# AVAudioPlayer playing Sound with very low volume in iPhone 6 and 6+

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am playing a sound using `AVAudioPlayer`.

The sound volume in iPods (iOS7 & iOS8 both) is good.

But when I play same sound in iPhones the sound is playing with very low volume.

Here is my code:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
var soundURL:NSURL? = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound", ofType: "mp3")!)

audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURL, error: nil)
audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer?.volume = 1
audioPlayer?.play()
```

I've already included **AudioToolbox.framework** library in my project.

**How can I improve sound in iPhone6 and 6+ ?**

**EDIT**

**Recently i noticed that automatically the sound was increased for couple of seconds,but don't know what's wrong happening.?**

Comment: You are not setting the volume of the whole device. Just depending on the mainVolume. Is the main volume on the same level??

Comment: yes `Volume` is set on full.

Comment: This seems silly, but is sound.mp3 not very loud?

Comment: It's playing loud in iPods but not in iPhone 6 and 6+.

Comment: And playing a Song in the Music-App is also the same Volume? Maybe the iPods are louder in general

Comment: Yes Music-App volume is cool and louder.

Comment: Could you try just adding .0 to your volume. 
 
-> audioPlayer?.volume = 1.0

Comment: did the float value append fix this? I'm experiencing this issue (amongst a bag of others with AVAudio)

Comment: no, Changin value to `1.0` didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think if you set the volume of AVAudioPlayer to 1, then the problem is on the system volume.
You may use a different audio category when playing your sound and the volume is different in different category or different audio route(like native speaker, headset or bluetooth) The default category in your app will be **ambient**, but the Music app's is **playback**.
You can try to adjust your volume when you are playing your sound rather than before it's played.

Comment: Can i change `ambient` to `playback`.?

Comment: Are you sure it's the case I mentioned above? The ambient sound won't play when background, but the playback will. You can try [AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:error:]. But you should attention that if your app is not a music player or something similar, apple may reject it.

Comment: You should know that even when playback category, your volume can still be adjust to a low value that is different to ambient or other categories.

Comment: So i did set category to `Playback`, have you any reference saying that my app can be rejected `if  my app is not a music player or something similar, apple may reject it.`

Comment: My app is `Recording` and `Playing` sound simultaneously, When i set category to `Playback` recording is stopped. When i set category to `PlayAndRecord` sound volume again slow.

Comment: Can't I use two category in One app.?

Comment: You can use multiple categories indeed, but at one time you are in one of them. You should know one volume is to one category, so you will have multiple volume values and it's user's choice to make different volume. You can just leave it alone.

Answer (score 71):

The volume is low because the sound is coming via the top speaker in iPhone(used for calling).

You have to override the AVAudioSession out put port to the main speaker.(bottom speaker)

This is the code that Route audio output to speaker

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, error: &error)
```

**Swift 3.0**:

```
do {
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
   } catch _ {
}
```

Comment: to set permanently: `audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker)`

Answer (score 15):

Solution for **Swift 4**

```
try? session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, policy: .default, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
```

**P.S.** For full class you can check my [gist](https://gist.github.com/sssbohdan/0cad6dacdb692e7890f1d9048008eef1)

Answer (score 2):

you need to maximize the media volume as well.

```
extension MPVolumeView {
var volumeSlider:UISlider {
    self.showsRouteButton = false
    self.showsVolumeSlider = false
    self.hidden = true
    var slider = UISlider()
    for subview in self.subviews {
        if subview.isKindOfClass(UISlider){
            slider = subview as! UISlider
            slider.continuous = false
            (subview as! UISlider).value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
            return slider
        }
    }
    return slider
   }
}
```

then change the volume like this :

```
func setMediaVolume(volume : Float) {
    MPVolumeView().volumeSlider.value = volume
}
```

in your case, setMediaVolume(1) right before you play your audio.

also make sure that the current audio route is to the Speaker and not the earpiece, you can do that using

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
```

Answer (score 2):

I also experienced this in the swift playground, the volume is much smaller than the sound in the original file. Just increase the volume.

```
audioPlayer?.volume = 3
```